# Change Cell Data Type within VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, math

I am writing an application in excel that helps you to learn the Completing the Square process. I want the cell to be formatted as Number if the variable is an integer, and formatted as a fraction if not.

```
If h = (Int(h)) Then
Range("D1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "Number"
Else
Range("D1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "?/?"
End If
```

This code doesn't work for some reason, giving me the following error:

> Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class

Are there any other ways I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
If h = (Int(h)) Then
Range("D1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Else
Range("D1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "# ?/?"
End If
```

However, if you format an integer as a fraction, it'll still show as an integer (i.e. "1" as a fraction is still "1").  So why not just format it as a fraction regardless?

Comment: id ditch the selects and go with range("D1").numberformat = "0" for example